# How to convert Azure DB URL to localhost DB URL?

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I've got an Azure SQL Server database that I'm connecting to via JDBC, but want to connect instead to my SQL Server "localhost". In SSMS, I connect to localhost without needing a password. So, do I still need to enter a password in Java?

I have a code like this :

```
 String connectionUrl =
                "jdbc:sqlserver://etcetc.database.windows.net:1433;"
                        + "database=med;"
                        + "user=windersan@salemimed;"
                        + "password=********;"
                        + "encrypt=true;"
                        + "trustServerCertificate=false;"
                       // + "hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;"
                        + "loginTimeout=30;";
```

How do I change this to connect instead to localhost?

Answer (score 1):

Just replace the `etcetc.database.windows.net` by `localhost` and replace the port number 1433 by the number that you are using.

I have used `SQLServerDataSource` class to make the work easier. You can also create a string URL and set it in the `DriverManger.getConnection()`.

Try with this code :

```
SQLServerDataSource dataSource = new SQLServerDataSource();  
dataSource.setUser("windersan@salemimed");  
dataSource.setPassword("********");  
dataSource.setServerName("localhost");
// set the port number of your system below.  
dataSource.setPortNumber(1433); 
dataSource.setDatabaseName("med"); 
dataSource.setEncrypt(true);
dataSource.setHostNameInCertificate("*.database.windows.net");
dataSource.setTrustServerCertificate(false);
Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
```

*Please refer to this links down below for more info.*

1. **[Microsoft Docs - ISQLServerDataSource Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/reference/isqlserverdatasource-interface?view=sql-server-2017) - This contains the list of methods that you can use to set the various properties in the datasource.**
2. **[Microsoft Docs - How to work with the connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/working-with-a-connection?view=sql-server-2017) - This contains examples of the possible ways to connect to a SQL Server database.**

Comment: @DevinAndresSalemi Is this helpful to you ?

Answer (score 0):

the first line of your concatenated string contains the url `etcetc.database.windows.net:1433` this is the location of the database server, and the bit you should change.

Also, it might be worth doing a google search on connecting to SqlServer with JDBC to see if there are any examples out there.